# Show an html element dynamically within a ng-repeat section using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat directive being used in html code as below. I would like the following html: '{{command.Title}}', to be only added if the command.Title was not an empty string. In other words I do not want divs to appear as empty divs when command.Title is an empty string.

**Question**: Is this possible and if yes, then how can it be done?

```
        <md-list class="control-panel-list">
        <md-item ng-repeat="command in controlPanel.commands">
            <div>{{command.Title}}</div>
            <md-button aria-label="{{command.text}}" class="control-button"
                ng-click="controlPanel.onCommandButtonClick($index)">
                <i class="{{command.iconCss}}"></i>
                <span class="reports-control-button-text">{{command.text}}</span>
            </md-button>
        </md-item>
    </md-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the `div` as part of the DOM at all, try using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`/`ng-hide`...

```
<div ng-if="command.Title">{{command.Title}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ng-show` to hide the element if empty:

```
<div ng-show="command.Title">{{command.Title}}</div>
```

Comment: So, ng-show will not render the div element if command.Title is an empty string?

Comment: it will render the DOM element, but ng-show will evaluate to false if command.Title is empty (because an empty string is a falsey value). When it evaluates to false, ng-show will set its CSS display to none. ng-if will not render the DOM element if the condition evaluates to false.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the precision @domitall. However for a simple text div it is move performant to simply hide/display it rather than remove/append the node to the DOM. But when you have a more complex div that contains other angular watchers, be sure to use `ng-if` indeed.